# How do I support arbitrary section depth?

Tags: sectioning, packages

Rather than subsubsection is there a sectionlevel{2}?
I am writing a rather large monograph and I need levels as deep as 10 such as:
1.2.3.4.5.6.7.8.9.1: This is a very deep section.

I have set \secnumdepth{10} but how do I use it?
Must I write a package of my own?
How can I use the \label and \ref capabilities or
must I re-implement these in my own package too?

Comment: the standard classes only have 6 levels 0 (chapter) to 6 (subparagraph) but it's not hard to add more if needed, just copy the definition of subparagraph as often as needed changing the `{5}` `\label and `\ref`  will work automatically.

Comment: Thank you.  I really did research to find this, and failed to find the duplicate.  I will find the original you described and add new levels to my preamble.  TNX.

Comment: it's always easier to find a duplicate (as egreg did here) if you posted an answer previously to a similar question, so don't feel too bad about not finding a dup.

Comment: Thanks all.  I managed to integrate and test the "\level{100}{title}" command.  I promise to return with more questions.  Not a question but... I make commands for composing and labeling images which I can then re-use several times in a single document.  I am thinking of parameterizing the command to make it possible to highlight elements in the figure.  Just saying but if there is a package for doing this already, I have duplicated it.